# How to pass $event object from my template to my component on Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, event-binding

I want to know briefly about event binding.

- How can I pass an event object from template to angular component not only as a method like

```
    <button (click)="onClick($event)">click me</button>
```

but also as object like
  `<button (click)="onClickObject">click me</button>`

- I wanna know if it is possible to access DOM objects inside component like javascript like
  `document.get.elementById('anyId')`
  after the button was clicked and manipulate them
- I wanna know how to pass the event object to the service class
- Finally how to solve these bug on my code of courses.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CoursesService } from '../courses.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-courses',
  template:`
  <h1 id="h1id">{{ greeting }}</h1>
  <button (click)="onClick($event)">click me</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./courses.component.css']
})
export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit {

greeting ="";

onClick(event){
this.greeting = "hi my name is ..."
console.log(event)
}
constructor(){
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  }
```

I get an error of *Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

src/app/courses/courses.component.ts:18:9 - error TS7006: Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type.

18 onClick(event){*

- I am using
  **
  Angular CLI: 13.0.3
  Node: 14.15.5
  Package Manager: npm 6.14.11
  OS: win32 x64
  **
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDPwY.png)

Comment: give type to the event in your function like `onClick(event: any)` or `onClick(event: Event)`. the error will be gone

Comment: It's depends which event do you pass because type of `$event` depends of context. In case of click handling `$event` is `MouseEvent` so you can easily access DOM element where event was triggered on, using `event.target`.
Useful links: [Event binding](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding).

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of Angular, we need to pass the argument type of any in-class component where we declare a function.

```
<button (click)="onClick($event)">Greet for Employee</button>
```

This one is code for the template.

`onClick(event: any){ console.log(event); this.greeting="Welcome Chetan"; }`

This is a code in-class component.
Here When I declared a function onClick, I have taken the event as any type of argument. Try this one.